# What to use in creating a hand held database application

Tags: ms-access, vba, windows-ce, jet

What program/programming language would be ideal for creating an Access like database on a Windows 5 CE hand held scanner?

We have tried Visual CE but it is not really something we can work with. Ultimately we would love to build a system where we scan a bar code, select a user from a drop down list, select basic options of division, location and moving from one location to another. Access would be perfect for this, but I cannot seem to find anything comparable.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about writing a database program for windows CE, or are you asking about writing a program for windows CE that used a database?

Comment: Think Access with forms, buttons and sparkles for the end user. I want to spend the least amount of time in development as possible.

Comment: Ok so what you are really looking for something like access that allows you to build forms and reports inside the "Access" file that when someone loads the file they get the forms and can interact with them which then stores it in the data backend that is part of the file. does that sound about what you are looking for?

Comment: Sounds about right. Mind you I am not opposed to doing it vb/sqlserver ce, just if there is something that is an idiots paradise, I would want to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a barcode scanner (like the symbol technology ones) running windows CE. You can easily use Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 and do your development in VB.net or C# (Though it requires at least the professional version of these annoyingly). For a database backend, there is a SQl Server Ce that is a smaller version of SQL server designed to run on a ce device.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) as the database backend for your application. It works well in embedded devices. It is [widely used](http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html) and you can get [professional support](http://www.sqlite.org/support.html).

Comment: You answered the part of the question that was unimportant. The fundamental question is not about the data store, but about the application development environment.